# How to get permission to execute a jar file?

Tags: permissions, java, files, security, jar

I successfully converted a .class file to a .jar file while playing around with Java (I'm new to it) and now I'm trying to execute it, however when I double-click on it to launch it, I got this error message.

[image]

Now I looked it up and it looked like other Linux users have encountered similar issues before, but I couldn't find any support for Ubuntu.

How can I get permission to run my jar file? I'm certain this is on Ubuntu's end and not Java.